# Android call with encryption and decryption

Tags: java, android, c, xml

How to do an encryption and decryption features in my application for a call. Is their any algorithm available for it?

Thanks in advance :)

I was sending one message that should be encrypted and reciever should reply same .when i recieve that same message it should match and gives automatic call to reciever.

Comment: check this link
http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [javax.crypto](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/package-summary.html) documentation for Android